# Teams Toolkit: Search based Message Extension not returning Adaptive-Card

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, imessage-extension, teams-toolkit

I kinda have an issue with the search-based Message Extension.
When I debug locally, my app works fine. After deploying the messaging extension on Azure and testing it in the Teams app, I can search for specific queries. The Message Extension gives me the desired results, up to here we are good to go.
The Problem:
After I select one of the delivered search results, the messaging extension does not return the adaptive card. The chat-box in Teams is simply empty.

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code sample and error messages (if any). We cannot help you if we don't know what you've implemented.

However, since you say it doesn't work in Teams, my guess is that your App Manifest is incorrect. Check the samples and ensure its correct.

Comment: Could you please share any sample or documentation that you are following?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you always reproduce this issue? I think you can retry several more times.

Or copy and paste the codes in `bot/teamsBot.js` here for troubleshooting.

Comment: Meanwhile I fixed the issue. The issue was inside the manifest-file. 
By default it was setup for the m365 environment. I had to change that :)